# What’s the best practices to interact with an external API using Yii2?

Tags: php, rest, api, frameworks, yii2

I am using a service which offers a complete set of RESTful endpoints to manage all my data (GET, UPDATE, etc.. are all supported).

The service also created a ready-to-use PHP class to easily interact with the API.

I autoload this Class using composer (and it's stored in vendor/my-class) so I can use it globally in my application.

Now the question is: Should I create a Model to wrap the Class methods? Or can I just put all the logic in the Controller and use the Class method directly in there?

What's the best practices here?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a model class that extends from `yii\base\Model` and create save, create and update methods, maybe even try to follow parts of the ActiveRecord pattern or another pattern that fits your needs.

Using `yii\base\Model` is essential IMHO if just to add the needed rules for validation, default values, etc.